# Using local certificates by IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2012

I've developed Web API service, that makes request ot another Web API, that need a personal certificate.

When I developed this service on my local PC, I've just used HttpClient like this:

```
_handler = new HttpClientHandler() 
{ ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic };
_client = new HttpClient(_handler);
```

And my personal certificate was taken from my PC.

Then I wanted to publish my project to IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

First I've installed all certificates on server and set up Application pool in IIS, IIS is launched by service user, but my API application use pool of my account (certificate is binded to it).  But when I'm trying to make a request, I get an exception like this:

```
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>An error occurred while sending the request.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
```

I think that my problem is that IIS can't use certificates, that I've installed on Windows Server.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This Windows Server 2012 R2 machine doesn't seem to trust the server certificate of the second Web API. Can you launch a browser (like IE) from this machine and navigate to that Web API? Certificate errors should appear then and you can see how to fix that (like adding the necessary root/intermediate certificates).

Comment: @LexLi Second Web API is working fine in browser. Probrems start when I try to use my service, published in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate must first of all be trusted, also access to reading the certificate can sometimes be a problem. check that IIS_IUSERS (app pool user) has read access:

[image: CertificateAccess]

A better solution might be to create a real certificate (non-selfsigned) 
 especially if this is a public api.

Those no longer cost money, with services like [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and tools for IIS like [win-acme](https://github.com/PKISharp/win-acme) (former lets-encrypt-win-simple) it will generate certificates for you for all bindings in your IIS but also has a lot of other options.

Answer (score -1):

Use this before your call to HttpClient . Remember this code is only for development machines. DO not use this in production

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate (
            object s,
            X509Certificate certificate,
            X509Chain chain,
            SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors
        ) {
            return true;
        };
```

Comment: The example says "please ignore security"

Comment: Yes. If you don't want to waste your time and money in buying and installing SSL certificates in dev machines..... Let the OP confirm which solution is preferable. I am sure which one was picked :)

Comment: Since the OP specifically mentioned IIS, Visual Studio can create a self-signed certificate for developer machine use.  It takes about 10 seconds for me.  For production use I'm assuming that security will be important enough to justify both the time and expense for certificates signed by a widely trusted authority.  Pushing security to developers, during development, generally leads to more secure deployed services.